# Change font type in grid.arrange text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the font type of text I am adding in `grid.arrange` but I don't know how to do it.

Please, see this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars) + ggtitle("title")

grid.arrange(
  p1,
  p2,
  nrow = 1,
  top = "Title of the page",
  bottom = textGrob(
    "this footnote is right-justified",
    gp = gpar(fontface = 3, fontsize = 9),
    hjust = 1,
    x = 1
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While typing the question, I found it. It is all in the `gpar` vignette.

Simply use `gpar(..., fontfamily="desired-font")`.

E.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars) + ggtitle("title")

grid.arrange(
  p1,
  p2,
  nrow = 1,
  top = "Title of the page",
  bottom = textGrob(
    "this footnote is right-justified",
    gp = gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySerif" , fontsize = 9),
    hjust = 1,
    x = 1
  )
)
```